# WPDB prepare - like % - placeholders?

Tags: wpdb

Are these `{xxx...}` placeholders for `%` in a LIKE statement normal? If so, when do they get converted back to `%`'s?

```
SHELL
wp> global $wpdb;
wp> $q = "%s";
=> string(2) "%s"
wp> $pq = $wpdb->prepare($q, '%hi%');
=> string(136) "'{6e039dc0b074a5ff6828a070d0c24708d132341f32dff55a053f1410beabaacd}hi{6e039dc0b074a5ff6828a070d0c24708d132341f32dff55a053f1410beabaacd}'"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they're normal. They were added in 4.8.3 to fix an SQL injection vulnerability.

You can read an article describing the technical reasons for this happening [here](https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2017/10/disclosure-wordpress-wpdb-sql-injection-technical.html) and the ticket for the change [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41925).

The placeholder characters are replaced by the random characters on the last line of `$wpdb->prepare()` with the `$wpdb->add_placeholder_escape()` function, which calls `$wpdb->placeholder_escape()` internally.

These placeholders are removed in `$wpdb->query()` by the `$wpdb->remove_placeholder_escape()` function which is added as a filter to the `query` hook.