# How to escape percentage sign(%) in sql query with $wpdb->prepare?

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb

I have the following code

```
$v12 = 'Milk(45% Fett i.Tr.)';
$sql = "INSERT INTO diary_data SET v2= '0.2', v12=$v12";
$final_sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, '');
```

but after echoing `$final_sql` contains

```
INSERT INTO diary_data SET v2= '0.2', v12=Milk(450.000000ett i.Tr.)
```

which is not right sql query.

I have tried adding extra `%` in `$v12` like `$v12 = 'Milk(45%% Fett i.Tr.)'`  which gives me

```
INSERT INTO diary_data SET v2= '0.2', v12=Milk(45{d4f1e7f215677fb8d2f6ba2935ed4333e2d215f3645e54e0669d65c881e609cd} Fett i.Tr.)
```

I have also tried using `$v12 = $wpdb->_real_escape('Milk(45% Fett i.Tr.)')` but now luck.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an incorrect use of `prepare`, that function is used to safely insert variables into queries. However the code in your question does this beforehand, bypassing the security function.

E.g.

What you did:

```php
$unsafesql = "INSERT $dangerousvariable";
$still_unsafe_sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, '' );
```

What it should be:

```php
$safe_sql = $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT %s", $dangerousvariable );
```

Comment: I have already tested with `$wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO diary_data SET v2= '0.2', v12=%s", $v12)` but i'm getting output like this `INSERT INTO diary_data SET v2= '0.2', v12='Milk(45{7d95f012bae8f751d3c4c22bf7111decd58d46978a8031246c7c989e2d75c24f} Fett i.Tr.)'`

Comment: @JoyKumarBera That's normal. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/303944/39152